# Error returning cell from tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am relatively new to using table view in ios. I am trying to edit data using different view and update the values from original view. I set cell identifier and wrote following code.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  
{ 
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NameIdentifier";
    Item *currentItem=[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
     cell.textLabel.text=currentItem.itemName;    
     return cell;
    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check and make sure `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` was able to dequeue a cell. It's crashing because it doesn't return a cell every time. If you were unable to dequeue a reusable cell you need to create a new one. Your code should look like this:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NameIdentifier";
        Item *currentItem=[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)  
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         // Configure the cell...
         cell.textLabel.text=currentItem.itemName;    
         return cell;
        }
```

Comment: But i figured it out... I am having dynamic data on view, thus, I wasnt supposed to return the cell. I deleted the methods from controller and it works fine now.